# How to Display Images According to the Original Size Using PHP Looping

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

I want to display images from database and display according to their original ratio or size like Deviantart. I'm using bootstrap 4, is there an example code for this?

Comment: did you tried,  `style = "height:100%; width: 100%"` on **img** tag.?

Comment: You have to post your code. such that anyone can understand your problem clearly. Image size depends on its parent dom. so, this is an issue to see your code first.

Comment: What is not working for you, the PHP, the DB code, or the Bootstrap?

Comment: I haven't made it because I haven't got the logic at all. If you look at the deviantart page, each image has a different size. whereas if I use looping, then the logic is that I have to be like this

``<div class = "row">
<? php foreach ($ image as $ i):?>
<div class = "col-md-4"> image here </ div>
<? php endforeach; ?>
</ div>``

But if the logic is like this, then each image will be displayed always in the size of col-4, not based on the ratio of the original image

Comment: You can see the grid here [deviantart](https://www.deviantart.com), not always 3 or 4 columns, sometimes also 2 columns